CVE prevention - guide
Where can I read about a specific cve (in my case CVE-2023-52251) and read how it works and how to prevent it?
I used rapid7 and metasploit to generate an attack but I still don't understand how does the attack work or how to prevent it.
Thank you,

does this help any? linked from NIST NVD (obviously this doesn't answer your question in your entirety but it looks like somewhere there's an eval with bad validation)

Here's a few different services you can use to search for specific CVEs:

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search
https://www.cvedetails.com/
https://www.cve.org/
https://cve.mitre.org/

For exploit code samples (e.g. to test that your project really is secure against an attack), check out this website:

https://www.exploit-db.com/

You can also get a bunch of good results if you just plop the CVE into a normal search engine, the above sites will usually be in the results, together with some vendor specific documents (like advisories) if there are any.
To understand an attack in detail, it can also help to look for
writeups and blogs about them.
In your case, you could search for something like "CVE-2023-52251 Writeup". It's not guaranteed that you find something, but better known attacks tend to be documented.
Hope this helps! ^_^
Edit: Added last paragraph
